# Cannot Execute Concurrent Chrome Dev Tools Performance Profiles

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103

I cannot stop more than one concurrent execution of Chrome Dev Tools Performance profiles running in separate sessions (tabs).

I want to use Dev Tools Performance profiling to measure application performance load, using two concurrent sessions.  So, run the application in tab 1, start Performance recording, and execute application step A; run the same application (or different application, it doesn't matter) in tab 2, start Performance recording, and execute application step B.  After a session's step finishes executing I attempt to stop its related Performance recording so that I can save the profile.

However, only the first session's profile can be stopped.  When I stop session 1's Performance recording I see a brief "Loading profile..." message which is then dismissed.  When I stop session 2's Performance recording I also see the "Loading profile..." message, but it is never dismissed, so I cannot save the profile.

Note: if I stop session 1's profile execution before starting session 2's profile execution, then I can stop session 2's profile execution with no problem.  The problem occurs only when both profiles are executing simultaneously.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Dev Tools' Performance profiling for concurrent monitoring as I am attempting to do?

Thank you.

Comment: It could be a bug or an inherent limitation. Try in Chrome Canary and in much older portable Chrome. Then maybe report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Agreed.  Thanks for the response.